# How to enable Email desktop alerts for inbox folders in outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outlook does not show desktop notifications on a message recieve](https://superuser.com/questions/89511/outlook-does-not-show-desktop-notifications-on-a-message-recieve)

Right now desktop alerts only comes if mail comes in inbox only . i need desktop alerts for every folder on incoming mail

Comment: I want to add the duplicate has a MUCH better answer, create a rule for all incoming mail!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How do incoming emails arrive in different folders? Different email delivery locations or custom rules?

If you use custom rules, add the action "Display a Desktop Alert" in the Rule Wizard, at the "Select action(s)" step where the "move it to the specified folder" is also defined.

[image]

If you have a different delivery location per email account (as defined in Tools-Accounts Settings, E-mail tab, button "Change Folder"), create a rule for each account and also set the action "Display a Desktop Alert".

[image]

Comment: +1 since I never noticed the "display a desktop alert" in rule actions :)

Comment: Thanks. This still applies to Outlook 2016.

Comment: This answer way worse them Duplicate answer, please see dup for creating "general" rule for all incoming mail!

Comment: Open rules, go to the second page by pressing next page, select "display a Desktop Alert". That's it

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Mail Alert](http://www.bettasoft.net/). It costs $3.95.

I'm using it in Outlook 2007 because you can also set it to notify you about any new mail that was moved to a folder by a rule. Of course I never noticed the "Display a Desktop Alert" option before Snark mentioned it.

However there's another thing why I prefer mail alert to default notification, that is the option to not dismiss notification automatically. Outlook only gives you option to increase visibility up to 30s before dismissing it.

Additional plus it that it works in Outlook versions 2000 / XP / 2003 / 2007.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a sound and display notification in the rules for emails sent to a specific folder.

Comment: And how would you do this??

Answer (score -1):

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. On the Preferences tab, click E-mail Options, and then click Advanced E-mail Options.
3. Under When new items arrive in my Inbox, select the Display a New Mail Desktop Alert (default Inbox only) check box.

[(source)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA100986701033.aspx)

Comment: this is already checked

Comment: as said in point 3, it's for the default inbox only, not for emails sorted in various folders

Comment: I must be missing something... How does this solve the notification for mail arriving in different folders, not as a result of a rule, _other_ than the "Inbox"?