# Get Outlook to Show New Message Icon for Subfolders

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, taskbar, rss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable Email desktop alerts for inbox folders in outlook 2007?](https://superuser.com/questions/73052/how-to-enable-email-desktop-alerts-for-inbox-folders-in-outlook-2007)

I use subfolders paired with rules to organise my Inbox, (for example, emails from SuperUser are sorted by a rule into a SuperUser subfolder)

For some reason though, Outlook only displays the New Message icon in the taskbar when the email arrives in the main Inbox folder.

So is there a way to make Outlook display the notification regardless of what folder the message actually arrives in?

Also if possible I would like the same thing to happen when I revieve new items in an RSS feed.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://superuser.com/questions/73052/how-to-enable-email-desktop-alerts-for-inbox-folders-in-outlook-2007

Comment: Ahh... Didn't see that before. Apologies

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that thread - the linked thread is referring to the popup indicator that appears when a new message arrives.  This question is referring to the icon that appears in the system tray.  I am looking for an answer for the system tray question, and the link did not help me at all.