# How to get Outlook 2007 to remember the option "Show an envelope in the notification area"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, notifications

My question isn't like this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/89511/outlook-does-not-show-desktop-notifications-on-a-message-recieve) I don't have rules routing my messages.  What happens is that Outlook will uncheck my option to show the mail icon.  Not sure how or why it does this.  How do I make Outlook remember or to leave alone that option?

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked to see if the Windows taskbar is set to not show the notification?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA101205831033.aspx

Comment: Yes I have it marked as always show.  As I said that isn't the issue.  The issue is that outlook unsets my setting.

Comment: Have you run all the updates available for Office/Outlook 2007?  Do you have any additional add-ons loaded in Outlook?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new profile?